# How do I fix line spacing between views in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

So I'm having an issue utilizing the compare feature in Notepad++ after recently upgrading to Windows 10. The spacing between lines is slightly off to the point that by the time I'm down to line 11 on the left view, it's only at line 10 on the right view and it's extremely aggrivating. Here's a screenshot to show what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1CJt.png

Follow the black lines and you'll note how it's off, starting small but becoming increasingly more spaced out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems the zoom setting is different for the views.
Use the Menu: View, Zoom, Restore Default Zoom  in both views.

With best regards,
Lars

Answer (score 16):

`Settings`->`Style Configurator`->`Global Styles`->`Brace highlight style`->`Font size`

[image]

Comment: One can also leave the font size empty. Then, the font size of the "Default style" is used.

Comment: I think this doesn´t work anymore in the recent versions of Notepad++

But alternatively you can change the Line number margin, and it works!

Comment: @FernandoVieira, you should add this as an answer so it's more clear. I almost didn't see your comment

Comment: @FernandoVieira It works (again?) in Notepad++ v7.1.1.

Comment: If this doesn't work try setting font name to blank. I had mine set to Source Code Pro and the font size wasn't affected

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Notepad++, to achieve the desired results, you should go to:

```
Settings -> Style Configurator -> Global Styles -> Line Number Margin
```

And set **Font Size** property to get the desired "line height".

[image]

The side effect is that your line numbers should be bigger than your text

Comment: THIS is the correct way on newer versions.  I *just* used it, in fact.